# How does Sencha Touch 2 build iOS apps on Windows?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sencha-touch-2

I was wondering about this at a technical level. I was given to understand that iOS apps could only be built on Mac OS X because you needed the toolchain that is bundled with Mac OS X and XCode.

So does anyone know how Sencha's app builder can build a native app on Windows too? And how come no one else has done it before?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are not the first to make an iPhone SDK for Windows. Adobe did it with Flash at some point, for example

Comment: This is not the kind of question that you should ask here, though...

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I've seen "How does X work?" questions being asked before. Downvoting was a bit harsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This info is without looking deeper into Sencha's packaging mechanism)

An *.app* file is represents a [bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html), which is essentially a folder with some files and *.plist* property file. The bundle also contains an executable, which in Sencha's case is likely always the same. The only purpose of this executable would be to kick off a UIWebView to display your app's main view. Beyond that, all programming you do with Sencha is standard web programming. Native API access from this application likely uses a clever URL-based trick ([just like PhoneGap](http://hiediutley.com/2011/03/14/phonegap-tutorial-series-1-project-structure-and-internals/)):

> Basically, PhoneGap works by intercepting URL requests for the
>   UIWebView that is loaded in the view. The PhoneGapAppDelegate
>   implements the UIWebViewDelegate protocol to detect and intercept
>   changes to the document.location of the UIWebView. Once intercepted,
>   PhoneGap interrogates the request to determine what to do with it.

As there is zero compilation needed, the XCode compilers are not required. The only part of the process I can think of requiring a Mac is creating the bundle [code signature](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html). Again, without looking under the hood of Sencha Tools, it is possible that this process has been reverse-engineered.

Comment: PhoneGap applications are native applications with an embedded UIWebView. I understand how the JS in a PhoneGap app has access to native APIs but PhoneGap still requires Mac OS X to build your app for iOS (because it's still a native app). Sencha doesn't seem to.

Comment: Judging from this forum posting, they are indeed using their custom code signing library: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?186165-Upload-application-to-app-store